# Modal blade validation isn't showing

Tags: laravel

I am updating a column by a modal blade form and I'm a bit confused about validation:

[image]

**modal.blade.php**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="baja_{{$id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="bajaModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" style="color: black;">Dar de Baja a {{$id}} </h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('contratos.baja', $id) }}">
                @csrf @method('PATCH')
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="motivo_baja" class="col-form-label" style="color: black; "><strong>Motivo:</strong></label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="motivo_baja" name="motivo_baja" style="width:100%; height: 150px;"></textarea>
                    @if ($errors->has('motivo_baja'))
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                         <strong>{{ $errors->first('motivo_baja') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <button id="cerrar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    <button id="dar_baja" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto">Dar de Baja</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm expecting to **validate** when the `textarea` is empty, I checked and it does, but isn't showing the message of validation in this part:

```
@if ($errors->has('motivo_baja'))
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
         <strong>{{ $errors->first('motivo_baja') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
```

**The problem:**

The variable `errors` seems like is not receiving errors. But like I said, when I don't write anything in the textarea and send the data, the table isn't updating, so, something is happening because the validation works but I don't know how to handle it. How can I handle those errors to show them in the modal and not simply close it without giving any message?

My controller **ContratoController.php**

```
public function baja(Request $request, $contrato_id){
    $request->validate([
        'motivo_baja' => 'required|max:300',
    ]);

    $contrato = Contrato::find($contrato_id);
    $contrato->motivo_baja = $request->get('motivo_baja');

    $contrato->save();

    return redirect()->route('contratos.index', $contrato->legajo_id)->with('success', 'Ok!');

}
```

I needed to make this column `nullable` like this in the **migration**:

```
$table->string('motivo_baja')->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS class invalid-feedback has a default value of display:none in bootstrap css, add the class d-block (assuming bootstap 4) or another class to override this css value and set display to block:

```
@if ($errors->has('motivo_baja'))
    <span class="invalid-feedback d-block" role="alert">
         <strong>{{ $errors->first('motivo_baja') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The `modal` is still closing after sending the data when I remove those classes. I'm expecting to the modal not to close if the `textarea` is empty but I'm confused

Comment: When a validate fails it redirects with errors the redirect will cause the the model to close, you need to trigger the model if the error occurs to reopen the model.

Answer (score 0):

You need Validator class in your controller `use Validator;`
Try samething like this

```
     $rules = array (
         'motivo_baja'  => 'required'       );
 $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules;
 if ($error->fails())
{
     return response()->json(['errors' => $error->errors()->all()]);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying this but it sends a lot of data

Comment: So? What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `required` and `autofocus` to the `<textarea>`